# how to open matlab using php (windows command line)

Tags: php, matlab

is there any php function to open Matlab using Windows Command Prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, several actually:

- [`exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
- [`popen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)
- [`system`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)
- [`passthru`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)
- [`shell_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)
- [`proc_ open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)
- [backtick operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)